# Flutter and Firebase Functions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: firebase, flutter

This is the error I am getting in the debud

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/3840] The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
#0      catchPlatformException
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/utils/exception.dart:21
#1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1378:47)
#2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1272:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:166:20)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:716:47)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:737:24)
#6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:547:5)
#7      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:264:13)
```

And the Fuunctions log has this error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at /workspace/index.js:19:33
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

The actual function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebaseTools = require("firebase-tools");

exports.delMessages = functions.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 250,
  memory: "512MB",
}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token && context.auth.token.admin)) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "permission-denied", "user must be logged in"
    );
  }

  const path = data.path;
  await firebaseTools.firestore.delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: functions.config().fb.token,
  });

  return {
    path: path,
  };
});
```

And the flutter invocation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

import './message.dart';

class ChatList extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatList({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatListState createState() => _ChatListState();
}

class _ChatListState extends State<ChatList> {
  Future<void> runDelMessage(String msgId) async {
    final functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
    HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('delMessage');
    await callable({'path': 'chat/$msgId'});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy(
            'createdAt',
            descending: true,
          )
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> chatSnapshot) {
        if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

        if (chatSnapshot.hasError) {
          print('there was an error');
        }
        final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
        final int chatLength = chatDocs.length;
        //final displayDocs = chatDocs.sublist(chatLength - 30);
        if (chatLength > 50) {
          runDelMessage(chatDocs[chatLength - 1].id);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            //controller: _scrollController,
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: chatLength,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Message(
                chatDocs[index].data(),
                key: ValueKey(chatDocs[index].id),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have checked the official [FlutterFire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/), and the code is mostly a copy of [Firebase Functions example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#web). The code suggests that the user token would be handled by the SDK. How else am I supposed to go about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the request was supposed to be a List if the Map has a single key.

The token also needs to be passed as data.